# submit() jquery method not work properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a form, and in certain condition, before submitting it I want to modify a value for an input. I do this with Jquery:

```
$('#form').submit(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        if($("#img").val() != "")
        {                       
            basic.croppie('result', {
                type: 'base64',
                size: {
                    width: 809,
                    height: 500
                },
                format: 'jpeg',
                quality: 0.8
            }).then(function (resp) {
                $("#imgModified").val(resp); 
            });
        }

        this.submit();
});
```

In server-side, in Chrome I get value of "imgModified" and I get the correct value, as expected. But in Firefox, I get empty string.

I have Firefox 55.0.3 and Jquery 3.2.1

Comment: "value" it is string ,u want to append value to this $("#input2").val("value"); try this var value='jj' ; $("#input2").val(value);

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: var id = document.getElementById('input2').value;  alert(id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `basic.croppie()` returns a promise as indicated by the `then()`.

Promises are **asynchronous**.

Do the submit inside the `then()` after the value is set

```
$('#form').submit(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var form = this;
  if ($("#img").val() != "") {
    basic.croppie('result', {
      // options left out for clarity
    }).then(function(resp) {
      $("#imgModified").val(resp);
      // submit native method, will bypass jQuery submit listener
      form.submit();
    });
  }else{
    // submit without $("#img").val() ??
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: Excelent! Works perfectly, great idea!

Answer (score 3):

It's a normal behaviour. if you want to change any value of your form by listening the submit event, you have to stop the default browser behaviour which is to send a request on the action you defined. (in fact the browser send the request before the execution of your code).

Then you can do your stuff and resubmit the form with javascript.

Try to do :

```js
$('#form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    
    if($("#input1").val() != "")
    {     
        basic.croppie('result', {
            type: 'base64',
            size: {
                width: 809,
                height: 500
            },
            format: 'jpeg',
            quality: 0.8
        }).then(function (resp) {
            $("#imgModified").val(resp); 
            $('#form').unbind().submit();
        });
    } else {
      $('#form').unbind().submit();
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="/test" method="get">
  <label for="input1">Input 1</label>
  <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text">
  <label for="imgModified">Input 2</label>
  <input id="imgModified" name="input2" type="text">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

**Update** :

This is the result i get on firefox by running the above code snippet : My request contains `input1` with my "tets" and `input2` with "value". Check if you don't have any problem in your server side.

[image: network Result]

Comment: Ok, it works. But I have to add a flag to prevent infinite loop. Thanks!

Comment: If I do return true; the form is not submitted.

Comment: doesn't matter what is returned after you prevent the default,  form won't submit

Comment: @JulienBourdic if I do $('#form').unbind().submit(); the form is submitted, but I get empty string in server-side (in Firefox).

Comment: @Josecanalla I updated my answer with the result that I get by running the code snippet on firefox. Check if you d'ont have any problem on your server code

Comment: I updated my question. I think there is a problem because of croppie method (a image library) is executed async?